# How to print out only the children from the findall result?

Tags: openxml, elementtree

Here is the xml markup

```
  <p:transition spd="slow">
    <p:push dir="u"/>
  </p:transition>
```

Here is my code:

```
    namespaces = {
       'p': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main'
    }

    transitions = et.findall('p:transition', namespaces)
    if transitions:
        # Only worry about the first node for now
        for p in transitions[0].iter():
            print p.tag, p.text
```

The print output is

```
{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}transition

{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}push None
```

I would like to skip the `p:transition` node. How can I tell `p:transition` is a parent node of `p:push`?

In addition, is there a easy to strip the expanded namespace prefix from the tag printout: `{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main}` (or in this case `p:push`  is fine)

Comment: *How can I tell `p` is the parent node?* Parent of what?

Comment: the question is updated